# Is it possible to find out itunes link for iOS application before it being submitted to appstore?

Tags: iphone, url, itunes

In my application I need to have one link which is directly conncect to the app store and it is the link of my application on iTunes App Store. Can anyone please let me know how to do it?

Comment: This is possible and you can see my answer as follows:

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can now use Short Links:

```
appstore.com/exampleappname
```

Just strip all white space from the app name. More in this Apple tech note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

Comment: This does not seem to be totally reliable. I tried it with some apps and it worked, but with others it does not. For example appstore.com/LayR does not work. appstore.com/LivingMemorySoftware/LayR takes you to the companies web page instead of the actual app itself.

Answer (score 24):

When you add the app to iTunes Connect, it gets an Apple ID (a 9 or 10 digit number). You can use a URL of the form `http://itunes.apple.com/app/id<your_id>` to link to your app in the store, for example http://itunes.apple.com/app/id417817520 if your Apple ID was 417817520.

The link will only work after the app has been approved of course.

Comment: Now you can use HTTPS

Answer (score 13):

We can generate the app link before the application being submitted to iTunes app store for review.

Here you need to follow the below mentioned steps.

(1) First login to your app store developer account and go to iTunes Connect.

(2) Then go to the option "Manage Your Applications".

(3) Now create new application here and add meta data and all the information about the application like Description, Category, Keywords, Price, etc. which can be edited later. Here you just remaining with the binary submission which you can do after adding the app store link.

(4) After creating your application here from the "Manage Your Application" section, you will get the Application listed. Now you select the app and then in the top menu click on More -> View on App Store.

(5) Now copy the link opened in the browser and that is the link of your application.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/appname/id123456789?ls=1&mt=8
- Where appname = name of the application
- id123456789 = it will be the ID of your App
```

These are the simplest steps to create APP store link before the app being submitted to app store actually.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how can I get developer id? I know I can get it in itunes by clicking on developer name blow App name. But since I am submitting first app from another account, so I need to know where I can find 9-digit developer/company id within itunesconnect or developer.apple.com? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can just use http://itunes.com/apps/[your company name]/[your app name].

Both the company name and the app name are without spaces and lowercase.