# Discovering the iTunes link of my app before submitting

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to find out itunes link for iOS application before it being submitted to appstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799737/is-it-possible-to-find-out-itunes-link-for-ios-application-before-it-being-submi)

I'd like to know the link of my App in the App Store before submitting it.
I know that the way is using the link:

> http://itunes.com/apps/appname

But my App have one name in iTunes Connect, and other in metadata of Application, that will appear in the App Store for users...
Which one I have to use in the link? The iTunes Connect project name or the metadata name?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcme to Stack Overflow! Please use the search before reposting question that have already been answered. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799737/is-it-possible-to-find-out-itunes-link-for-ios-application-before-it-being-submi

Comment: I searched, but didn't find this one... It is exactly what I want!! Thanks!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is already live, then just open up iTunes Connect, find your app and click view in AppStore. Otherwise, if your app isn't live...

Your App URL is not available until your app goes live, but most apps follow the same link pattern:

> http://itunes.com/apps/yourappnamewithoutspaces

Make sure that the app name has no spaces, or %20, or any characters for that matter. My apps on the AppStore have special characters like dashes, etc. and the link is just the plain text form of the app name.

**The name in the link will be the name displayed on the AppStore NOT the iOS device**. And by iTunes Connect Project name, I believe you're referring to the AppStore name.

Here's another SO post on links: [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

Comment: So is the name that is displayed in the App Store?
Thanks man!! :D

Comment: FYI App doesn't have to be alive to get link in iTunesConnect. Check my answer

Comment: @Nekto Hmmm... Before my app went live, the option you mention was not available as I remember, of course I can't check that now. Thanks!

Comment: @Nekto Doing what you said, it redirects to none App, but the link that redirects show the iTunes Connect App name, not the metadata...

Comment: @LeonardoBortolotti of course it will redirect at none App if your app is not released....

Comment: @RazorSharp it is so. I just checked it one more time

Answer (score 2):

You could find app link in the following place:

*iTunes Connect* (https://itunesconnect.apple.com) -> *Manage Your Applications* -> *Select your application* -> *Link table* -> *View in App Store*

Comment: this button is no longer available.