# Open app store with link not working

Tags: swift, app-store

I'm currently using this code to open the app store to my app (which is on iTunes connect but not released yet):

```
 if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.rateButton {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "itunes.apple.com/app/id0000000000000")!) }
```

It won't open in the simulator or on my phone in testing, is this because the app isn't yet released or is my code wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think The link will only work after the app has been approved.

Reference from the omz's answer from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799737/is-it-possible-to-find-out-itunes-link-for-ios-application-before-it-being-submi).